# VS 2013 tag completion breaks angular expression

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013

When editing Angular html templates in Visual Studio 2013, I have found that pasting into an angular data-binding expression in an ng-href attribute triggers some kind of autocomplete or auto tag completion that breaks the tag. It is easy to fix, but it is a serious annoyance and it only started recently. It does not seem to be caused by resharper, because I disabled that and it still occurred.

The bad autocomplete only seems to happen in ng-href attributes. When I have an existing attribute like ng-href="/path/{{vm.entity.entityId}}" and I paste into the angular expression, the tag completion strips the trailing Id}}" from the attribute. For example:

```
<a ng-href="/app/cities/edit/{{vm.city.CityId}}">edit</a>
```

when I paste over the "city" in the expression, I get:

```
<a ng-href="/app/states/edit/{{vm.state.City>edit</a>
```

Has anyone else seen this? Is there any way to see the specific list of items in the autocomplete/tag completion list to remove or edit whatever is doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I can disable this behavior by going to Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Advanced and setting "Format on Paste" to false. I do not consider this a complete answer, because it does not explain why this is happening, or fix the specific problem, just disables an entire feature (not that I am really missing it). I would still welcome more info or a fix to the specific behavior.